# Gulp libsass/autoprefixer error on comments in sass file

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass, autoprefixer, gulp-autoprefixer

I am switching from gulp-ruby-sass to gulp-sass. Gulp ruby sass was working without errors, but to make life easy on our Windows devs I am trying to remove the dependency on Ruby.

I installed the packages at set up my gulp file like so:

```
    var sassFiles = './app/assets/sass/**/*.{scss,sass}';
    var cssFiles = './app/assets/css';
    var sassOptions = {
      errLogToConsole: true,
      outputStyle: 'compact'
    };
    var autoprefixerOptions = {
      browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    };


  gulp.task('sass', function () {
     return gulp
    .src(sassFiles)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(autoprefixer(autoprefixerOptions))
    .pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(cssFiles))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

Except it fails every time over the comments in my file:

```
[08:20:39] Starting 'sass'...

events.js:154
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
 CssSyntaxError: /Users/stevelombardi/github/designsystem-  3/app/assets/sass/design_system.scss:1:1: Unknown word
 ////
 ^
/// This is a poster comment.
```

which maps to a comment in the scss file.  Note that even if I remove this block, sass simply errors on the next comment.

If I **comment out the autoprefixer pipe it works**.  So what's the issue here?

FWIW, I was following the guidelines from [this site](https://www.sitepoint.com/simple-gulpy-workflow-sass/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no Javascript-style single-line `//` comments in CSS, [only multi-line `/* */` comments](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/syndata.html#comments). 
Single-line `//` comments are supported by SASS/SCSS, but [stripped from the resulting CSS](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments).

Since `autoprefixer` only operates on CSS not SASS/SCSS you need to run `sass()` before `autoprefixer()`:

```
.pipe(sass(sassOptions).on('error', sass.logError))
.pipe(autoprefixer(autoprefixerOptions))
```